# Border-right moves when I switch between pages in navigation panel (HTML)

Tags: html, border

Whenever I change pages, the border-right element shifts right or left depending on the page. It is hard to demonstrate since I can only add one HTML file but can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The
nav ul{
}
elements are the same in every HTML file by the way.

oof its telling me I have too much code and that I need more textoof its telling me I have too much code and that I need more text

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background-color: #b3d8f5;
}
nav ul {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #4063ff;
  border: 4px solid #111111;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 2px solid #111111;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111111;
}
table {
  font-size: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
th {
  background-color: #61ffc9;
}
td {
  background-color: #9effd7;
}
nav li.selected {
  color: #020091;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  a:hover {
    color: #2b2b2b;
  }
  a:active {
    color: #05ff43;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Awesome Website!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');
</style>
    <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-6279648748308214" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css", rel="stylesheet", href="index-stylesheet.css"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li class="selected">Home</li>
        <li><a href=thingy2.html>A cool video</a> </li>
        <li><a href=thingy3.html>A cool picture</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1> My Awesome Website</h1>
    <p>Isn't  my website so awesome??</p>
    <button onclick="f()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
function f() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  }
}
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Website</th><th>Awesomeness Level</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>My Awesome Website</td><td>100%</td>
  </tr>

</table>
  </body>
</html>
```